# Java convert object to Class how?

Tags: java, typeconverter

My code is:

```
public static Object mylang;

public static class lang_eng {
        public static final String x="Refreshing..."; 
}
public static class lang_de {
        public static final String x="Refreshing..."; 
}
```

...

```
   if (LANG.equals("1")) {
        mylang=(lang_eng)new Object();
    } else {
        mylang=(lang_de)new Object();
    }
```

but when I reference `mylang.x`, I get: "x cannot be resolved or not a field"

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Can I recommend using Java's internationalization support? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html

Comment: You should edit: 'mylang.x then i get: "x cannot be resolved or not a filed" ' it is not code

Comment: FYI. The word "I" is always capitalized in English, never "i". Things like that make it look like you didn't put any effort into the question and so, over time, are likely to affect whether you get good answers. I've fixed it (and the thing Fgblanch complained about) for you in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the way object-oriented programming works.

If you want `LangEng` (not that in Java the standard naming convention uses CamelCase, not underscore_separation), then you have to instantiate it, using `new LangEng()`. But even that way you won't be able to access `x`.

What you can do in this case is to define an interface with a method `getX()` and let both language implement it. Then you can have `Language mylang`.

What's more - it's not a good idea to use this approach for i18n. Better use [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

Comment: What you can do in this case is to define an interface with a method getX() and let both language implement it. Then you can have Language mylang. -> can u show an example please?

Comment: @lacas as I said, it is not a good choice to use this for i18n. As for the interfaces and stuff - I'd suggest you read some articles about OOP and Java. this is basic stuff and you can't go on without it.

Answer (score 0):

As T.J. Crowder said i would use internalization support.

But just in case you need some extra functionality the code should be like:

```
public static Object mylang;

if (LANG.equals("1")) {
   mylang=new lang_eng();
} else {
   mylang=new lang_de();
}
```

And when you want to use it:

```
if(mylang instanceof lang_eng){
   lang_eng langTemp = (lang_eng)mylang;
   System.out.println(langTemp.x()); 
}

if(mylang instanceof lang_de){
   lang_de langTemp = (lang_de)mylang;
   System.out.println(langTemp.x()); 
}
```